# Alternative Implementation of GetEnumerator() for IEnumerable<T> Wrapper

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, ienumerator

I was implementing a wrapper class for an `IEnumerable<T>` the same way I usually do and I noticed that ReSharper suggested that I convert the `foreach` loop in my `GetEnumerator` method to a LINQ-expression.

Out of curiosity, I clicked "Convert into LINQ-expression" which then changed my method from:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach (var item in _someList)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

into ReSharper's "LINQ-expression" result:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<T>) _someList).GetEnumerator();
}
```

The code is pretty straight forward: rather than looping through `_someList` there, it is casting `_someList` as an `IEnumerable<T>` and then using whatever existing `GetEnumerator()` method their is to return the same result.

I haven't seen this implementation before, and I'm wondering if there are any dangers to using it in situations where you really don't have anything custom to put in the Enumerator. I'm also wondering if there are any benefits to using one implementation over the other.

Comment: It's because do not reinvent the wheel

Comment: ``IEnumerable<T>``  already has enumerator implementation written in framework

Comment: @Ehsan - That's what I was thinking, to be honest. But that is also why I was so surprised that I haven't seen this implementation before. It does make perfect sense.

Comment: The only obvious problem that immediately jumps out is if _someList doesn't cast to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: You do not need to implement GetEnumerator()

Comment: @PhilCooper - my class is a wrapper for `IEnumerable<T>` and `_someList` is the private `List<T>` field. I hear you on that, though, for similar but different situations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your non-generic `GetEnumerator` already works perfectly (except for being non-generic), then there is no reason *not* to use it. In this case, you would want to simply cast to `IEnumerable<T>`.

If it does not, then you will need to roll your own with the `yield` statements, as you already know how to.

Comment: I like this answer, a lot. That's a solid rule of thumb.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel As Ehsan Sajjad said, don't reinvent the wheel. It really is a solid rule of thumb.